# How to set onClick for multiple checkboxes programatically

Tags: android, android-checkbox

Without any Extra explanation I just want to set my Checkboxes to the same `onClick` programmatically , this is my Code:

## xml:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="func"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/c1"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:onClick="func"
    android:id="@+id/c2"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:onClick="func"
    android:id="@+id/c3"/>
```

## javaCode:

```
public void func(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?


    CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c1);
    CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c2);
    CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c3);

    if(checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked() && (!checkBox3.isChecked()))
    {
        Next = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Next = false;
    }
}
```

However I want a programmatical approach.

I'm looking for a way something like :

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox(context);
CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox(context);
CheckBox checkBox3 = new CheckBox(context);

checkbox1.setOnclick(//TheFunction);
checkbox2.setOnClick(//TheFunction);
checkbox3.setOnClick(//TheFunction);
```

`TheFunction` is the same as `func` in my previous code.

In other words i want a unique function to be called when any checkboxes is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

**try this make your check boxes like this**

add same `android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"` method to all your check boxes like below check box

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/c1"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    android:id="@+id/c2"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    android:id="@+id/c3"/>
```

**now in your activity file create a method of** `onCheckboxClicked` like below

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

// now check that Is the view now checked?
boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

// Check which checkbox was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case c1:
        if (checked)
            //  c1 is cheked
        else
            // c1 is uncheked
        break;
    case c2:
        if (checked)
            // c2: is cheked
        else
            // c2: is ubcheked
        break;

 }
}
```

try this

```
chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
               if(isChecked){
                    fun();
                }

   }
}
);
```

Comment: all of my checkboxes are created programmatically

Comment: i didn't get you my friend

Comment: oh sorry , can you explain a little bit about your approach

Comment: thank for your guide , but onCheckboxClicked is just called whenever checkbox_meat is clicked, i want the same for other checkboxes

Comment: Sorry , i forgot to mention some points , read the updated one

Comment: @shahingh can u explain in brief

Comment: yes, my Checkboxes are created programmatically , i assign Id to each one , then i want whenever each one is clicked the same function will be called .  
just like my previous code ( with Xml) .

Comment: @shahingh check update ans your can do like that attach `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to your all checkboxes and when it check your can call a functio like this

Comment: Thanks for your effort , however is there any other neater way ?  because in this way i must to set this method for checkboxes individually

Comment: you can create just one method for all and call that method from `setOnCheckedChangeListener`  like i have done in above code where i'm call `fun()`

Answer (score 0):

You can set **onClickListner** to your **checkbox** like this

```
 checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
            if(cb.isChecked()){

            }else{

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: so i must use this method for buttons individually ?

Comment: Yes, then what do u want?

Comment: I wish if would be any Neater way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

> checkbox1.setOnClickListener( //The function);
>
> checkbox2.setOnClickListener( //The function);
>
> checkbox3.setOnClickListener( //The function);

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat the same onClickListener code again and again, create this method

```
private void setOnMyViewClick(View myView)
  {
    if(myView!= null)
    {
      myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          try
          {
            myViewClick(v, v.getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId()));
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {

          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

create a method that process the click

```
private void myViewClick(View view, String viewName) throws Exception
{

}
```

and register the onclick for any checkbox or any other view

```
setOnMyViewClick(checkbox1);
```

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

        try {

            if ((view == c1) || (view == c2) || (view == c3)) {

                // You can perform a common action for all check box clicks here

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("onClick", e + "");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do different events for each checkBox you should do like `Nilesh Rathod` answered.